# Print results in a list in output file in python

Tags: python, spyder

I'm trying to print a list in a csv file. The code as is prints the list in the console but when I push it to print in a csv, it prints it in a clustered array.

Here is the code:

```
for pred in y_pred1:
    resultsFile = open('results.csv', 'w')
    print(y_pred1, end='\n', file = resultsFile)
    resultsFile.close()
```

For that segment it outputs the file, but the output looks like this:

```
[0.         0.02466293 0.04371493 0.07445887 0.10470171 0.1899941
 0.         0.02395268 0.04299739 0.07386746 0.11551061 0.32383927
 0.         0.02564607 0.04576736 0.07179424 0.10852157 0.18824359
 0.         0.02395268 0.04299739 0.07386746 0.11551061 0.15899986
 0.         0.02655989 0.05173249 0.08852134 0.02564607 0.04576736
 0.07179424 0.10852157 0.02564607 0.04576736 0.07179424 0.10852157
 0.15423326 0.         0.02395268 0.04299739 0.07386746 0.11551061
 0.         0.02564607 0.04576736 0.07179424 0.10852157 0.15423326
 0.         0.02395268 0.03308567 0.05735641 0.12299032 0.
 0.02679364 0.03308567 0.05735641 0.12299032 0.16938186 0.25925685
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
 0.        ]
```

I want it to output as a list with each result in a new cell like so:

```
result 1
result 2
result 3
result 4...etc
```

If I run the same code without outputting it to a file, it produces the list in the console exactly how I want it. As soon as I specify that I want it in a file, it becomes a cluster.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are passing a list object to `print` as a single argument. You can use asterisk when passing the list of values as a list of positional arguments to `print`:

```
print(*y_pred1, end='\n', file = resultsFile)
```

But, for what you are doing it is a best to use the `csv` module.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: I added the asterisk but that didn't sort out the output in the file. Let me explore changing the method. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.